# LOOKUPVALUE Returning Rounded Value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am attempting to pull a single value by using LOOKUPVALUE and it is doing so, but instead of returning the value, which is a decimal, it is rounding up to the nearest whole number.

Here's the code that I've tried and and example table of my data set.

```
Measure = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    'Monthly Values'[Requested Value],
    [Month Num],
    MONTH(TODAY())
)
```

To be clear, [Month Num] is the Month in numerical form so January = 1, Feb. = 2, etc.

Here is an example table:

```
Month         Irrelevant    Month Num   Requested Value
1/1/2019    6584651         1           2.48
2/1/2019    6516516         2           2.36
3/1/2019    3464            3           3.32
4/1/2019    6584814         4           2.72
```

Requested Value is formatted as a "Decimal Number" and limited to 2 decimal places. Also before someone asks, I have double checked the Measure to ensure the measure's formatting is also set to "Decimal Number" with 2 decimal places.

For this case the month is 4 and the formula should spit out "2.72" but instead is spitting out "3".

Is there a way to get around the rounding with LOOKUPVALUE? Alternatively is there another way to lookup this value which would not round the returning value?

Comment: Can't reproduce this behaviour, with that sample data and measure. Post a PBIX file?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. What I did was to change the data type to decimal in the Power Query, then load the data to Data model (simply refresh the data).

Mine is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use following dax

```
Measure = FIXED(
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        'Monthly Values'[Requested Value],[Month Num],MONTH(TODAY())
    ),
2)
```